# Lightning Carousel data has 0 rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-card

im develop a lightning web component with an apex call wich in his initial deployment the query return 0 rows, but in a future time will be used, and the query eventually will return data but the following error is displayed:

[image: error]

i can't control the error in the front because my function is not the issue, but the carousel.js is a standard class from the component itself.

this is my html:

```
<template>
        <lightning-card title="Próximas Campañas" icon-name="custom:custom11">
            <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
                <div class="slds-box_x-small slds-m-around_small">
                            <lightning-carousel>
                                <template for:each={campaigns} for:item="campaign">
                                    <lightning-carousel-image key={campaign.id}
                                        src = {campaign.ruta_imagen__c}
                                        header = {campaign.Name}
                                        description = {campaign.Description}
                                        alternative-text = {campaign.Name}
                                        href = {campaign.campaignUrl}>
                                    </lightning-carousel-image>
                                </template>   
                            </lightning-carousel>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if:false={areDetailsVisible}>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-var-m-vertical_small">
                    No hay campañas vigentes actualmente
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getLastCampaign from '@salesforce/apex/CampaignCarousel.getLastCampaigns';


export default class campaignCarousel extends LightningElement {

    areDetailsVisible = true;
    campaigns;
    campaignLoadError;
    @wire(getLastCampaign) campaignsWireHandler({data,error}) {
        if(data) {
            if(data.length > 0 ){
                this.campaigns = data.map(value=>({...value,campaignUrl:`/${value.Id}`}));
                this.campaignLoadError = null;
            }
            else{
                this.campaign = data;
                this.areDetailsVisible = false;
            }
        }
        if(error) {
            this.campaigns = null;
            this.campaignLoadError = error;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope u guys can help me with this. if u have any idea let me know.

Comment: do you have more than 5 carousel-images rendering within the carousel itself? I think it doesn't support more than 5 images, you might want to check the code's repository -> https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/carousel/carousel.js

Comment: This actually happens when the query of the apex class return 0 rows, when the query has data works perfectly fine, i try to declare the campaign data from the wire null when it returns empty but the error still happen. In my query i have the sentence LIMIT 5 to restrict the carousel data limit.